# SQL using nested INSERT INTO's?

Tags: sql, postgresql, schema

I am using `postgreSQL` for storing chat logs, and I have this sample schema:

```
CREATE TABLE contacts (
  "id" BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  "user" BIGINT NOT NULL,
  "contact" BIGINT NOT NULL,
  "savedAs" VARCHAR(36),
  CONSTRAINT user_fk FOREIGN KEY("user") REFERENCES users("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT contact_fk FOREIGN KEY("contact") REFERENCES users("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  UNIQUE("user", "contact")
);

CREATE TABLE messages (
  "id" BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  "contact" BIGINT NOT NULL,
  "direction" direction_type NOT NULL,
  "type" message_type default 'text',
  "body" VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
  "status" status_type DEFAULT 'none',
  "time" TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  CONSTRAINT contact_fk FOREIGN KEY("contact") REFERENCES contacts("id") ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE last_message (
  "id" BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  "chat" BIGINT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  "message" BIGINT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT message_fk FOREIGN KEY("message") REFERENCES messages("id"),
  CONSTRAINT chat_fk FOREIGN KEY("chat") REFERENCES contacts("id") ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

What I want to do, is store the last message for a particular chat in the `last_message` table. I was thinking of doing it like this(but not working):

```
 INSERT INTO last_message (chat, message) VALUES (
     9,
     (INSERT INTO messages (contact, direction, body) VALUES (9, 'sent', 'hello there') RETURNING id)
 )
```

But I get a syntax error(`syntax error at or near "into"`), so here are my questions,

- what is wrong with the above query?
- is there a better a way to do this? how?
- is there anything that can be improved?

Comment: Note: your `last_message` has a natural key problem. last_message for/from whom ? (that would probably need to be unique)

Comment: `last_message` stores the last message for a particular chat whether sent or received doesn't matter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgres insert value from insert in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46318925/postgres-insert-value-from-insert-in-other-table)

Answer (score 1):

Use a CTE:

```
WITH toinsert as (
      INSERT INTO messages (contact, direction, body)
          VALUES (9, 'sent', 'hello there')
          RETURNING id
     )
INSERT INTO last_message (chat, message) 
    SELECT 9, id
    FROM toinsert;
```

Answer (score -1):

Step 1

```
drop table last_message
```

You can get the last message like this:

```
select contact, direction, body
from messages 
join 
(select chat, max(time) maxTime
from messages
group by chat
) temp on messages.chat = temp.chat
and time = maxTime
```

You can create a view or whatever with this logic, whatever your requirements happent to be.