# Postgres insert value from insert in other table

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, database-sequence

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_a (
id serial primary key NOT NULL,
name text NOT NULL,
tbl_b_reference NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE tbl_b (
id serial primary key NOT NULL,
status text)
```

I want to do two inserts. One in tbl_b, and then use the id from that insert when I do my insert into tbl_a.

I've tried this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_a(name, tbl_b_reference) 
VALUES ("myName", (INSERT INTO tbl_b (status) VALUES ('OK') RETURNING id));
```

but I only get a syntax error pointing at the second "INTO"

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "INTO" Position: 68
```

Where do I go from here and is it possible to do this without writing permanent functions or creating triggers? I'm new to postgres and just know some basics of MySQL/MariaDB. I've been searching around here for other questions related to nested inserts but couldn't find something that I managed to actually use, so code examples would be much appreciated.

Comment: `"myName"` is a column reference, not a string constant

Comment: Is this not what foreign keys are for?

Comment: Also: `tbl_b_reference NOT NULL` needs to be: `tbl_b_reference integer NOT NULL references tbl_b`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The last comment did the trick! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Related: [PostgreSQL nested INSERTs / WITHs for foreign key insertions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21386772/190597)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need a common table expression for this kind of insert chaining:

```
with ta as (
  INSERT INTO tbl_b (status) VALUES ('OK') 
  RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO tbl_a (name, tbl_b_reference) 
VALUES ('myName', (select id from ta));
```

Another option is to simply use the `lastval()` function to reference the last generated sequence value:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_b (status) VALUES ('OK');
INSERT INTO tbl_a (name, tbl_b_reference) 
  VALUES ('myName', lastval());
```

Note that you must not have any other statements that generate sequence values between those two.

Or use the currval() function:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_b (status) VALUES ('OK');
INSERT INTO tbl_a (name, tbl_b_reference) 
  VALUES ('myName', currval('tbl_b_id_seq'));
```

`'tbl_b_id_seq'` is the standard name Postgres uses for a sequence that is created for a `serial` column:

Comment: Getting an error "relation \"ta\" does not exist" with this :\

Answer (score -1):

I really like the WITH ... AS solution mentioned above by [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) since this is the only atomic solution achieving this in one single statement.

If however you feel fine doing it in two statements there's a fourth easy way to do this: with a subquery and **max()**.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_b (status) VALUES ('OK');
INSERT INTO tbl_a (name, tbl_b_reference) 
  VALUES ('myName', (SELECT max(id) FROM tbl_b));
```

Personally I find this better than *lastval()* cause it only depends on this specific sequence not being next()-ed in between the statements and also better than *currval()* since there's no need to know the sequence name.

And it's the most readable solution too.